# What's the difference between \u0061, \x61 and \141 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]

Why the first expression can be executed without error , but the second and the third one can not be executed?

Comment: The latter two are only allowed in string/regex literals.

Comment: Where can I find the official document that specified this rule?

Answer (score 3):

The spec allows it:

> Unicode escape sequences are permitted in an *IdentifierName*, where they contribute a single Unicode code point to the *IdentifierName*. The code point is expressed by the *CodePoint* of the *UnicodeEscapeSequence* (see 11.8.4). The `\` preceding the *UnicodeEscapeSequence* and the `u` and `{ }` code units, if they appear, do not contribute code points to the *IdentifierName*. […]
>
> https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-names-and-keywords

In other words, you can use `\u....` escape sequences as replacement for literal characters for identifiers (such as `console`). The same allowance is *not* made for other kinds of escape sequences like `\x..`.